# Adding GIF to xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to include gif files as a static resource in iOS app. I am using FLAnimatedImage library. I am able to load gif from the net and show using:

```
FLAnimatedImage *image = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:@"http://raphaelschaad.com/static/nyan.gif"]]];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

I have to load the GIF statically from local resources instead of fetching it from online. something like:

```
NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:LOCAL_FILEPATH
```

I am unable to add a gif to image assets but would like to include the image in local files. How do I do that?

PS: I am new to iOS development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you already known your path then you can call directly like

```
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"yourGifImageName" ]; // it take from assests
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

else if you want to load from bundle

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"youranimated.gif" ofType:nil]];
FLAnimatedImage *image = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL]];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: It worked. I wasn't using NSBundle to access the resource.

Comment: nice bro, your coding is fine , I just optimized have a nice day